# Character reference "&#x10" is an invalid XML character

Tags: java, xml, gradle, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have migrated my project from java-8 to java-9 but post the migration i am getting xml parsing error in some job which is running.

The project is a gradle project and i have added the necessary changes in build.gradle to add jaxb dependencies.

Below is my build.gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.3'

        compile "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:win"
        compile "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:win"
        compile "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11:win"
        compile "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11:win"



        compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'

        compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0'
        compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.0'
        compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.1'
        compile 'com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0'
        compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-ri', version: '2.3.0', ext: 'pom'
        compile group: 'javax.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-api', version: '2.3.0'

        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: "${junitVersion}"
        testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: "${springVersion}"
        testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '1.9.5'
    }


Below is the error that I'm facing(Occurs randomly but too often):

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,379459]
Message: Character reference "&#x10" is an invalid XML character.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.EwsXmlReader.isEmptyElement(EwsXmlReader.java:1037)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.EwsXmlReader.readElementValue(EwsXmlReader.java:358)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.definition.TypedPropertyDefinition.loadPropertyValueFromXml(TypedPropertyDefinition.java:133)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.definition.StringPropertyDefinition.loadPropertyValueFromXml(StringPropertyDefinition.java:34)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.PropertyBag.loadFromXml(PropertyBag.java:510)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.ServiceObject.loadFromXml(ServiceObject.java:298)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.SyncResponse.readElementsFromXml(SyncResponse.java:158)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.loadFromXml(ServiceResponse.java:133)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.parseResponse(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:76)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.parseResponse(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:44)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.readResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:433)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.readResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:401)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:63)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Yes Arvind.. I went through the link but it did not provide sufficient information. Also i'm not sure how to change the xml parser version in gradle project. If you can help, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all occurrences of `&#x10;` with the correct XML numeric character reference `&#xa;` (or, of course `&#10;`, the decimal equivalent).
Then the error should vanish.

Comment: Hi zx485, Thanks for your reply.. but modifying the existing data seems to be difficult as the data is fetched from exchange.. Is there any other way around? or am i missing some dependency? Also the characters are different(not &#x10; always) most of the times. so there should be some fix for all the characters at once.

Comment: The problem is that `&#x10` is not a valid _XML 1.0 entity_ as @Arvind Kumar Avinash wrote in the comments above.

Comment: There are few more characters which are not a valid XML 1.0 entity. So is there a genuine solution to tackle all the invalid characters?? i think changing xml parser version might be one but not sure how to do that for my project?

Comment: I don't think that changing the XML version would be a good idea, because if `&#x10;` was used as a linebreak, it may have been just a typo and changing it can create **a lot** of follow up errors. I tried to find a `DOCTYPE` solution for redefining character references, but I didn't find one.

Comment: Ok.. so what i'm getting is that using &#x10; in the xml is an error.. to use line feed either "&#10;" or "&#xA;" should be used.. right?? If we use &#x10; in the xml then it should be considered as bad data... right??

Comment: AFAIK this is the case. I cannot help you any further.

Comment: @zk485 Thank you so much..I think that's it..It is bad data and should be taken care of..Your insights were really helpful.. Thanks again.